# Comparing a word from a list of words in an array C++

Tags: c++, arrays

So I am basically trying to figure out how to compare a word from a text file to a bunch of words in a array. I've no idea on the logic of doing this.. My code so far which displays saves all the words from a text file and stores them into an array. I now want to compare the words in the array to a different text file. But I'm not sure how I would loop this all.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream infile("words.txt");

int i = 0;
string array[9];

while (!infile.eof())
{
    for (int j = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

        infile >> array[i];


        if (!infile.eof())
        {
            cout << array[i] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `for (int j = 0; i < 10; i++)`  I think you need to take a careful look at your loop counter variable(s).

Comment: SO is no substitute for learning to program. Study hard and eventually you will learn how to program. When you say "I've no idea on the logic of doing this" I doubt the program at hand is your real problem.

Comment: How about printing the result of `array[i] == word_to_be_compared`? You also study about [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find). Also you are running out of bound. Increase the size of array or decrease loop iterations.

Answer (score 1):

You have *two* problems (at least)!

The first is that you should not loop while `!infile.eof()`, that will rarely work as expected. The reason being that the `eofbit` flag is not set until *after* you try to read from *beyond* the end of the file, so the loop will iterate once to many.

The second problem is that you have an array of nine strings, but you read *ten* strings, leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) when you write out of bounds of the array.

The first problem can be solved by remembering that all input operations return the actual stream object, and that the stream object itself can be used as a boolean to see if all is okay. The second problem can be solved by using [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead, or by reading only nine words or by increasing the size of the array to ten.

Or you can use `std::vector` and read all "words" (space delimited strings) in the file into the vector by a single initialization using [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator):

```
std::vector<std::string> words(
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>(infile),
    std::istream_iterator<std::string>());
```

After the above declaration, the vector `words` will contain all space-delimited "words" in the file.

---

To solve your problem of comparing to another file, then create two vectors like shown above, and compare each word in the first vector with the corresponding word in the second vector. But be careful to check that you don't go out of bounds of any of the vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an array, you could use a set. You can put in all words from one file and then just check for each word of the other file, if it is contained. If you want to make it work fast, you may consider using a hashset (in C++ this will be std::unordered_set). You can check for existence of an item within an average time complexity of O(1).